# Is it possible to make Spring instantiate only the parent bean in an inheritance (not instantiate child bean)?

Tags: java, spring

I have 3 classes.

1. An abstract class, abstractA with a protected constructor
2. A class extends the abstract class, parent with a couple of constructors
3. A class extends the parent class, child with one constructor

   ```
   @CustomComponent
   public abstract class abstractA {
     Object var1;
     Object var2;
     Object var3;

     @Autowired
     protected abstractA(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3){
       var1 = arg1;
       var2 = arg2;
       var3 = arg3;
     }

   }
   ```

This is the parent class that extends from abstract class

```
@CustomComponent
public class parent extends abstractA {


      @Autowired
      public parent(Object arg2, Object arg3){
        this(arg1FromSomeEnum, arg2, arg3);
      }

      protected parent(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3){
        super(arg1, arg2, arg3);
      }

    }
```

This is the child class that extends from parent

```
 @CustomComponent
 public class child extends parent {

      @Autowired
      public child(Object arg2, Object arg3){
        super(arg1FromSomeEnum, arg2, arg3);
      }

    }
```

The custom component looks like this

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype")
@Inherited
public @interface CustomComponent {
  String value() default "";
}
```

So when spring instantiates all beans for a particular test, it instantiates, child bean correctly. When the parent bean is instantiated, it gets 2 beans [parent and child]. So, I end up getting error,

> Multiple beans of type parent

Now, what is wrong here ? How to get the instantiations right ? Should I use @Qualifier or @value, if so where and what ?

Comment: Do you have any class level annotations, like @Component? Could you please specify what is your expected result? Maybe paste the code of the test.

Comment: Yes. The classes have @Component annotations. The expected result is not to get the error. I need only one bean to be instantiated for the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use @Qualifier annotation.
Following link explains it in more detail.
[Using @Qualifier annotation to create unique beans](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/)